# How can I create an 'Edit button' in my display form?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, form, edit-form, edit

I am modifying my display form at the moment via code in SharePoint designer 2013. 
People feel its difficult to find the Edit button on the top left corner of the SharePoint display form and always "searching" for the button at the bottom next to the 'close' button.

Do you know how to create an edit button and provide some code? :)

Thanks!

Comment: Please refer the link for SharePoint Client-side rendering (JS Link). This will help you out - http://www.winwire.com/sharepoint-2013-client-side-rendering-2/

Comment: I have no idea about JS Link, sounds pretty complicating to me.. :/

Comment: Edit the page, and add Content Editor Web Part.

Comment: Where should I edit the page? I just want to edit the display view.. not sure what you mean

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the "edit button" in your list view you can do the following steps:

1.) Modify the view of your list

[image]

2.) Check the column "Edit (link to edit item) and save the view

[image]

3.) Click on the edit icon in your view. This will open the list item or the document properties directly.

[image]

Maybe that's an option for you

Comment: Hi, thank you first! 
My problem is that the people I'm working with feel its intuitive to click on the item first and then they are searching for the edit button when they are in the display item view already. That´s why I thought I make it easier for them and insert an edit button in that view.

Answer (score 1):

Go to "Form Web Parts" 
Click "Default Display Form"
[image: Under List Click "Default Display Form"]

Add a webpart
[image: Add WebPart]

Add a content editor
[image: Add Content Editor]

Once you have added these you can write a HTML code to insert a button for the Display Form.

```
<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="Edit Item Button">&nbsp
```

Comment: I just copy and pasted it and then I had a button named 'Edit Item Button' :D 
Thank you so much!!

Comment: One more question: I can see the edit button, but how can I put the link in it? It should lead to the EditForm of the same item so how can I do that?

Comment: Do  you know how to attach the link?

Answer (score 0):

What About going to List Settings > Advanced Settings > Dialogs (Yes) to turn on the dialogs option. This makes the Item Display open in a pop up like form. The edit button is hard to miss.

[image]